# Calculate average values of points intersecting grid

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, table

I'm using QGIS 2.18.16.
I have a layer with 100k locations, each with several values in the attribute table (ex: mass, E impact, v, ...) for each point (imported via CSV file).
I use a vector grid to count the number of spots for each square of 5m by 5m = ok so far. This gives me a heatmap of the number of hits.

I would like to add to each square an average of another value of each spot. (from csv file and in attribute table of hits layer)
Ex: square A, has 250 hits(= individual values) those are already counted. But those hits in square A have each a different Energy impact. I would like to get the average E impact of these hits in each square for the same vector grid.
This gives me different heatmap in the same vector grid. Not with the number of hits per 5x5m square but with the averag E impact.

The final goal is to generate a final layer by multiplying 2 or more values (number of hits, average E impact, presence of people, ...) for each same 5x5m square to obtain a final kind of heatmap that combines those factors for each 5x5m square.

Can this be done?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation of the goal. I have been struggling with a similar challenge for a couple of hours now. I'm finding myself almost screaming "This shouldn't be so hard!" :-)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest [refFunctions](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) plugin.

If your *Telling* layer is the grid, and *Data* layer is the points,

[image]

Open the attribute table of the *Telling* layer, and start Field calculator. Then create a new field with an expression `intersecting_geom_sum( 'Data', 'E impact')/"hits"`.

(assuming "hits" is the field you have stored the number of hits).

[image]

Then *Telling* attribute table would be like below.

[image]

Comment: Hello. This works perfect! Is there a way that i can specify this for a specific square or a specific set of squares? This would save me a lot of time by not calculating squares that are not relevant.

Comment: @stijngeldof It will be technically possible, by adding a condition such as `IF` or `CASE WHEN` functions. However it will increase the computation time, probably not what you want to. Sorry...

Comment: Thank you  Kazuhito, what would the correct expression be like then? with the IF or CASE WHEN functions. I would like to give it a try and compare both computation times.

Comment: @stijngeldof Yes, if you have a field with a categorical value to specify such group; Let's say `"group"` field with 'A' and 'B'. Then `CASE WHEN "group" = 'A' THEN intersecting_geom_sum('Data', 'E')/"hits" ELSE 0` .....(or something like that).

Comment: I can't calculate it with this: 
when  "id" = '710' then intersecting_geom_sum( 'WND0519_WT02_Ijsval finaal v2.12_Datareeks 1_990k', 'Overlijdenskans - Task 19')/"Numpoints" else ='0'

Comment: @stijngeldof  This might be short-sighted response without looking at your data, but your output field must be either numeric or string. First calculation will return an numeric so `else='0'` also has to be numeric, such as `else=0`. (without single quotation marks, which changes number to text).